# How can I set setNotificationOpenedHandler method in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

In order to use push notification I used onesignal.When user taps the notification,It should navigate to screen.For doing it I need setNotificationOpenedHandler method.However it is missing.I can see OneSignal.Notifications.addForegroundWillDisplayListener((event) { }) method but not

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
    print('"OneSignal: notification opened: ${result}');
});
```

method

I read the onesignal documentation but there is no special info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ///
    /// This will be called when a notification is received while the app is open.
    /// This code works only -onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.2
    /// You can use that then OneSignal initialized

    OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
      debugPrint("Notification Clicked: $event");
      
    });
```